# gettext won't build libintl.so

Tags: gettext, musl

I am trying to get `libintl.so` compiled on musl-based distro, but running `./configure && make` in the directory containing source code, which I get from https://savannah.gnu.org/projects/gettext/ does not build any libintl objects. Furthermore, `libintl.h` seems to not exist in that directory as well. What's the deal?

Comment: Could you share the full build log?

Comment: The file `libintl.h` is not included in gettext but used if present (and usable) on your system. In the output of configure you will find the lines "checking libintl.h usability..." and "checking libintl.h presence..." that show the results of this test.

Comment: You should also be aware that the tarball that you download contains the sources for the gettext-tools and gettext-runtime. The shared library `libintl.so` that you want to build is part of `gettext-runtime`.